# WARNING in ./node_modules/moment/src/lib/locale/locales.js Module not found

Tags: .net-core, angular8

When iam running npm start command. Iam getting this error. Could you please help us to resolve this problem

I have tried 
1. deleting node_modules folder
2. yarn upgrade.

[image: error when running npm command]

Answer (score 4):

Just downgrade your moment by running:

`npm install moment@2.24.0`